# Split details section into two rows

Tags: crystal-reports

My Crystal report currently outputs like so:

```
## ID ##     ## Name ##       ## 1  ##          ## 2 ##          ## 3 .. ## 

  216           Ashraf      earlyout late    earlyout late         absent

  217           Aymen          late         earlyout late         absent
```

Is it possible to split rows into rows, for each employee? Like this:

```
## ID ##    ## Name ##       ## 1  ##          ## 2 ##         

         |          | Eo  |  earlyout    |      earlyout 
  216    |   Ashraf |-----|  --------    |---------------          
         |          | Lt  |   late       |      late
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Rearrange your Details section by simply resizing the fields and formulas. This will allow you to display two rows of data per every Employee row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

> 1. Open crystal report.
> 2. Right click the field you want to wrap.
> 3. Select Format Object.
> 4. Click the CheckBox `Can Grow` and set the `maximum number of lines` to 2 or any as long as you want.

Sample Text Field

From

```
My Sample
```

Result:

```
My
Sample
```